# Upload multiple file to different url's using ng2-file-upload

Tags: angular, file-upload, angular2-http, ng2-file-upload

I am having trouble `uploading multiple file to different urls using ng2-file-upload method`.

I am using this repo https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload 
to make this. `ng2-file-upload` is easily integrated in my app using this [demo](http://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/) to upload files. Also, they provided a [method](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload#api-for-ng2fileselect) to upload multiple files on a particular url.

But I want to upload `different files at different url`, which I am not able to find out yet.

```
// sample code
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload';

const URL = '/api/some_url';

@Component({
  selector: 'simple-demo',
  templateUrl: './simple-demo.html'
})
export class SimpleDemoComponent {
  public uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: URL}); // here to add url
}
```

This `FileUploader` provides way to give `url` to upload file. Usefulness of this method is that, `progress-bar` and related feature are integrated with this `ng2-file-uploader` component. I have searched a lot but not able to find any solution to upload to different urls.

Any useful suggestion will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how i was able to do the same.
You would have to override onBeforeUploadItem of the uploader.

define:

```
this.uploader = new FileUploader({url: this.uploadUrl});
```

in the constructor

```
this.uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = (fileItem: FileItem): any => {
  // logic of connecting url with the file
  fileItem.url = 'http://localhost:3001/path/v1';

  return {fileItem};
};
```